# Android and missing function getTextGlyphs

Tags: java, android

Android **Paint** class has a function to get text glyphs ([see android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/kitkat-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/Paint.java)):

```
public int getTextGlyphs(String text, int start, int end, int contextStart, int contextEnd,
            int flags, char[] glyphs)
```

This function does not exists when I developing in eclipse:

[image]

This function exists at least on Android 4 and my target platform is Android 4.4.
Any body has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented in [Paint Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html), which means it's not part of the public API. The confirmation is the fact that the source javadoc comment has the @hide attribute.

Comment: How Can I use this function?

Comment: You could use introspection to access and call it. But because it's not documented, it's not supported, and may change in future versions of Android. What are you trying to do, anyway? There may be another way to do it.

Comment: Thankyou for reply, I currently have done it by java reflect.